# How to add line break after every 5th string in a list on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
listMethods = dir(str)

listMethods[ : ] = [x for x in listMethods if not "__" in x]
```

listMethods contains all the different methods for string class. I want to try and organize it into five columns.

Comment: Please provide an example of input data and expected output.

Comment: You can use a generator directly in your sample, E.g., `[x for x in dir(str) if not "__" in x]`

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the list in fives, and print each five as a single string separated by spaces:

```py
for i in range(0, len(listMethods), 5):
    print(" ".join(listMethods[i: i+5]))
```

To achieve a more aligned format, you can use format fill with the longest method. Something like:

```py
maxlen = max((len(x) for x in listMethods), default=15)
for i in range(0, len(listMethods), 5):
    print(" ".join(f"{method:{maxlen}}" for method in listMethods[i: i+5]))
```

Gives:

```
capitalize   casefold     center       count        encode      
endswith     expandtabs   find         format       format_map  
index        isalnum      isalpha      isascii      isdecimal   
isdigit      isidentifier islower      isnumeric    isprintable 
isspace      istitle      isupper      join         ljust       
lower        lstrip       maketrans    partition    replace     
rfind        rindex       rjust        rpartition   rsplit      
rstrip       split        splitlines   startswith   strip       
swapcase     title        translate    upper        zfill
```

Comment: You should provide a greater-than-zero default for `max` in the second example.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! Indeed it is better for the general case. Added

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
# listMethods = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
listMethods = [x for x in dir(str) if not x.startswith('__')]
listFinal = []
for i, element in enumerate(listMethods):
    listFinal.append(element)
    if i % 5 == 0:
        listFinal.append('\n')

print(listFinal)
```

**Output**:

```
['capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', '\n', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', '\n', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', '\n', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', '\n', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', '\n', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', '\n', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', '\n', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', '\n', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

To view results:

```py
print(', '.join(listFinal).replace('\n, ', '\n'))

# Output
capitalize, casefold, center, count, encode, 
endswith, expandtabs, find, format, format_map, 
index, isalnum, isalpha, isdecimal, isdigit, 
isidentifier, islower, isnumeric, isprintable, isspace, 
istitle, isupper, join, ljust, lower, 
lstrip, maketrans, partition, replace, rfind, 
rindex, rjust, rpartition, rsplit, rstrip, 
split, splitlines, startswith, strip, swapcase, 
title, translate, upper, zfill
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate` inserted of the counter

Comment: added `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way to add a list item with the string '\n' after every 5 items:

```
for i in range(5, len(listMethods), 6):
    listMethods.insert(i, '\n')
```

Is this the functionality that you're looking for?